# login problems in deployed, why?

Tags: php, cakephp

i am new with cakephp ... i made a web aplication and deployed to hostgator and it's giving me this error

```
Missing Method in UsersController
Error: The action index.html is not defined in controller UsersController
```

I uploaded an older version of the same proyect without the login part and it works fine...

i don't know where's my mistake, I suppose it's in login part.
[This is](http://www.endyourif.com/cakephp-2-x-login-system/) the sample login page where i copied the code from.

My AppController

```
class AppController extends Controller {  
    public $components = array('Auth', 'Paginator', 'Session', 'Search', 'RequestHandler');

    public $helpers = array('Html',
                            'Js' => array('Jquery'),
                            'Session');

    public function beforeFilter() {
        $this->Auth->loginRedirect = '/';
        $this->Auth->authError = 'You must be logged in to view this page.';
    }   
}
```

UsersController

```
class UsersController extends AppController {
    public $name = 'Users';
    public $uses = array('User');
    public $components = array('Auth' => array(
                                 'loginAction' => array(
                                     'controller' => 'users',
                                     'action' => 'login',
                                  ),
                                 'authError' => 'Did you really think you are allowed to see that?',
                                 'authenticate' => array('Form')
                              )
                         );

    public  function logout() {
        $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
    }
    
    
    public function login() {
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $loggedIn = $this->Auth->login();
            if ($loggedIn) {                
                         return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
                //Success
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Username or password is incorrect'), 'default', array(), 'auth');

            }
        }
    }
```

login.ctp

```
    <?php
         echo $this->Session->flash('auth');
        echo $this->Form->create('User', array('action' => 'login'));
        echo $this->Form->input('username');
       echo $this->Form->input('password');
       echo $this->Form->end('Login');
    
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to access http://users/index

However, you do not have an action called 'index' for you to be able to access it. You can try  to access http://users/login

You will also have to refer to isAuthorized () and see if this is required. In your AppController, you can add the following for now:

```
  public function isAuthorised (){
   return (true);
}
```

Additional changes may be required.